# How to assign const char ** path as a string?

Tags: c++, macos

I want to get the working executable directory at runtime for OS X.  I found this code below, but I don't know how to use the `const path` as a string.  It's complaining that:

```
testingtesting.cxx:7:30: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the
  argument has type 'const char **' [-Wformat]
printf("path is : %s\n", path);
```

I want to assign the `const char **` path as a string.  Here is the code below:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, const char *argv[], const char *env[], const char *path[]) {
  // path[0] now contains the path to the executable
  // NOT PORTABLE! OS X ONLY!

    std::string s = path.c_str();

    printf("path is : %s\n", s);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `path` isn't a `std::string`, its a pointer-to-`char`.

Comment: Why is this question tagged [c]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
std::string s = path.c_str();

printf("path is : %s\n", s);
```

to:

```
std::string s(path[0]); // create C++ std::string and initialise
                        // from C string `path[0]`

std::cout << "path is : " << s << std::endl;
```